# Visualization issue with folium on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, maps, folium

I am trying to mark a location on a interactive map. So I did some research and finally managed to output  a map. Like this:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[51.0, 9.0], max_zoom=6)
m
```

Then I went on and tried to mark a location on the map like this:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[51.0, 9.0], max_zoom=6)
folium.Marker([51, 8]).add_to(m)
m
```

But instead of a map I get a white space as output:

[image]

And I went on multiple websites but most of them did it like that. So does someone know why it doesn't work and could tell me?

Comment: When I use your code it works. Did you try playing around with the `tiles` attribute? E.g. setting it to `tiles='Stamen Toner'`? Or the `max_zoom=13` attribute? E.g. `max_zoom=13'`? What does happen when you do `m.save("index.html")`? Does it output anything at all?

Comment: Also can you try to use `zoom_start` instead of `max_zoom` and see what it does?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. The tiles don't work but the rest does.

Comment: Could it be that I forgot to import something?

Comment: Well I reckon you did a `import folium` before? I don't see anything else wrong with your code. Do you have a screenshot what happens? Where are you running this? In a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I did import folium and I run this in a Jupyter Notebook. I will add a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Can you give this a try in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) and see if it behaves there the same way? Maybe your Jupyter is misbehaving with imports.

Comment: I tried it in Google Colab and there it works

Comment: In your Jupyter Notebook can you try to install `folium` via `import sys` and `!{sys.executable} -m pip install folium` first thing and see if this solves it?

Comment: I tried it and it tells me that the Requirement is already satisfied. And it still does not work. And thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please, provide the output of `print(folium.__version__)`. Then, what browser are you using?

Comment: Thank you very much you were right it was the browser. I used edge and then tried it in chrome and there it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens to get this kind of visualization issue with edge browser.

Try Firefox (or chrome), instead.